# Strange error when decreasing double value

Tags: java, user-interface

While developing an application I've found a serious error. But first some details: I've wanted  to display a temperature on a GUI. The temperature is a double value. The user should be able to increase/decrease the temperature. The goal was to emulate a heating/temperature valve for the heating unit. In addition to have random values, the user should be able to increase/decrease this value by using the GUI. Basically the value is intialized on startup with 20.1 (just a random value I setted at the beginning).

I've noticed a strange behaviour when I tried to decrease the temperature. Everything works finde when incrementing. But decreasing the temperature (by stepsize 1) leads to the following: 20.1 , 19.1 , 18.1, 17.1, 16.1, and then 15.100000000000001, 14.100000000000001 etc.

What's the reason?
The error does just occur, when using values ending on .1. So it does make no difference when trying with a base value of 22.1 or 31.1.

The error always occurs with the change from 16.1 to 15...

It's reproducable everytime. I've wrote a test application, feel free to try it:

```
package devices;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

/**
 * the temperature
 */
private Double temp = 20.1;
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test frame = new Test();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 271, 152);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 235, 56);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 19));
    lblNewLabel.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Increase");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            temp = temp + 1;
            lblNewLabel.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(10, 78, 101, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Decrease");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(137, 78, 108, 23);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            temp = temp - 1;
            lblNewLabel.setText(String.valueOf(temp));
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
}

}
```

Greetings and thanks in advance,

Julian

Answer (score 1):

0.1 isn't a round number in binary, so you can't always step evenly by tenths.  Example [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/).  If tenths are the finest resolution you need, store them as an `int` and display them manually:

```
(temp/10).toString() +"."+(temp℅10).toString()
```

This was what Turbo Pascal did for amounts of money, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Double, and others default float point representations, is a discrete representation for an infinite range os values (between two integers there are infinite values: 1, 1.1, 1.11, 1.11, ... 2).

So, many values don't have a exactly representation.

You should round your number to the precision you need.

Answer (score 0):

See this

[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html]

then use BigDecimal instead of Double.